# Rename Application Package

Tags: android, google-play, android-package-managers

I am planning to rename application package before submitting to playstore. 
I used maps, facebook, twitter in my project.

While registering app to google console and facebook, we have given package names there. 
So, do we need to edit package name at all those places.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You have to update your new package name everywhere.

Comment: It may work fine now. Try logging out of facebook and log in back again and you ll see a dialog saying the developer hasnt configured the app properly.

Comment: also the map not displaying but dont remember to change in manifest also

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You need to update on all maps, facebook, twitter etc. Because these server allow access to their API by identifying your app with unique package name with your app name. So if you change then these server consider your app is something different and they wont allow you access.